# Min Max values of a random Array

Tags: java

I am having some issues getting my min and max values to print. Also as new 
as I am to programming I don't understand why all my values are decimals. I will post the code and my results.

```
 import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class RandomArray1 
extends ArrayList<Double> 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public RandomArray1() 
        {
            super(); 
        }

        public static RandomArray1 getInstance(int size)
            {
                Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
                RandomArray1 randomArray = new RandomArray1();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {  
                    randomArray.add(randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble()); 
                }   

                return randomArray;
            }      



        public Double getAverage() 
        {
             if (this.size() == 0) 
            {
                 return 0d;   
            }

             Double sum = 0d;

             for (Double element : this) 
                {
                    sum = sum + element;  
                }
             return sum / this.size();
        }


       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter how many numbers you would like to Generate: ");

            RandomArray1 randomArray = RandomArray1.getInstance(scan.nextInt());

            System.out.println(randomArray);
            System.out.println("Average" +randomArray.getAverage()); 

            double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            while (true) {

                if ( !scan.hasNextDouble())

                    break;

                Double num = scan.nextDouble();

                min = Math.min(min, num);
                max = Math.max(max, num);

            System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
            System.out.println("Min is: " + min);
       }
    }
    }
```

Here are my results...

Enter how many numbers you would like to Generate: 5
[0.8630040934474159, 0.12949667753808425, 0.5751777190226718, 0.18492672539115063, 0.7508377917335503]
Average : 0.5006886014265746

always decimal point and it doesn't even print "Max is:" or "Min is:" which makes me think something is wrong with this section. But I don't know what it is...any thoughts. Just ideas...

```
while (true) {

            if ( !scan.hasNextDouble())

                break;

            Double num = scan.nextDouble();

            min = Math.min(min, num);
            max = Math.max(max, num);

        System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Min is: " + min);
```

Comment: The program is waiting for you to type in a number because of `scan.hasNextDouble()` in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program works fine:

```
Enter how many numbers you would like to Generate: 3
[0.26063976207509887, 0.48867331377683443, 0.3864751544223266]
Average0.37859607675808665
4
Max is: 4.0
Min is: 4.0
5
Max is: 5.0
Min is: 4.0
3
Max is: 5.0
Min is: 3.0
end
```

But since it expects an input, but doesn't say so, it could appear to be "dead". Just include a prompt before waiting for the next input:

```
System.out.print("Please enter next number: ");
if ( !scan.hasNextDouble())
    break;
```

In case you wanted to calculate the min/max of the existing array instead of a new user input, use a `for` loop to iterate over the existing array:

```
    for (double num : randomArray) {
        min = Math.min(min, num);
        max = Math.max(max, num);

        System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Min is: " + min);
    }
```

Comment: ok, but what I really want it to do is give me the max and min of the values printed originally...not sure how to though.

Comment: @Savage99: If you replace your `while` loop by the last piece of code I posted, it will do exactly that!

Comment: I did that....it worked. However now it gives me a min max readout for every number generated...even thought they are the same. I think I understand why just not sure how to fix it. It is because it is stuck in the loop...so how do I fix that?

Comment: @Savage99: Well, you said it yourself, it's because it is in the loop! If you don't want that, put the `println` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're filling you're array with `nextDouble()` which as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble--) gives you double precision floating point numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: thanks...I changed to Integer and it fixed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All good, changed the Arraylist to an Integer and everything else. This solved my issues as discussed. here is what the code looks like now...works perfect!

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomArray1 
extends ArrayList<Integer> 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public RandomArray1() 
        {
            super(); 
        }

        public static RandomArray1 getInstance(int size)
            {
                Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
                RandomArray1 randomArray = new RandomArray1();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {  
                    randomArray.add((int) randomNumberGenerator.nextInt()); 
                }   

                return randomArray;
            }      



        public Double getAverage() 
        {
             if (this.size() == 0) 
            {
                 return 0d;   
            }

             Double sum = 0d;

             for (Integer element : this) 
                {
                    sum = sum + element;  
                }
             return sum / this.size();
        }


       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter how many numbers you would like to Generate: ");

            RandomArray1 randomArray = RandomArray1.getInstance(scan.nextInt());

            System.out.println(randomArray);
            System.out.println("Average : " +randomArray.getAverage()); 

            int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            for (int num : randomArray) 
            {
                min = Math.min(min, num);
                max = Math.max(max, num);



            }
            System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
            System.out.println("Min is: " + min);

       }


    }
```

thank you so much!